# R: Rotate text independent of scaling (using mtext)?

Tags: r, plot, graphics

There are two ways to create rotated axis labels in *R*:

- `text(srt = angle)`

  - Advantage: Arbitrary angle possible (like 45°)
  - Disadvantage: y position changes with y scaling
- `mtext(las = 1)`

  - Advantage: y position fixed independent of y scaling
  - Disadvantages: Only discrete values possible (90° steps)

Is there a way to add rotated axis labels of whom the y position does not depend on the scaling of the y axis?

Comment: Please consider adding a small example to your post to make it more useful (and accessible) for future visitors. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking about the problem, I found a solution making use of the `ylim` parameter to the `plot()` function:

```
ylim = c(0, 0.5)
plot(...)
text(..., srt = 45, y = 0.2 * (ylim[2] - ylim[1]))
```

dynamically adjusts the position of the text according to the scaling of the y axis.